# Angularjs routeProvider adds *?* or %3F to URL with optional parameter

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand why Angular keep adding `?` or `%3F` to the URL when I have optional parameter in the URL

```js
$routeProvider
.when('/:locale?/', {
  templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
  controller: 'myController',
  title: 'Title'
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
});
// html5mode
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

The URL will end up with http://myexampledomain.com/en-US%3F/

I'm not sure what other information that I should provide to help getting the right answer here, but please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`$routeProvider` and `routing` does not work with query strings, and I think that angular thinks that you are trying to use them rather then defining optional params.

I do not think you are defining your optional params correctly in your route I belive that you need to do it this way:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:locale?', {
    templateUrl: '/views/index.html',
    controller: 'myController',
    title: 'Title'
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Notice that I Removed the `/` after your route and now i think angular should be able to recognize this route with optional params.